# Know which textBox has focus in xaml?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, xaml, windows-8

I have 3 textboxes that will change while it's being typed on a 4th one. I have tried the TextChanged="function" and change the content of the other three, but by chaging the .Text property, the event TextChanged is triggered again providing an undesired result. I was thinking of checking which textbox has the focus at the time, but I have no idea on how to implement that. I am experienced with Java and I'm very frustrated with all this c# and XAML. Thank you in advance.

Comment: When a TextBox gets the focus, the (appropriately named) GotFocus event should fire. The syntax is `GotFocus="myMethod"`.

Comment: Do you know how to trigger an event on KeyUp? If I add KeyUP="myMethod" it would not compile.

Comment: Sounds like you need to use the MVVM architecture and have this 4th textbox UpdateSourceTrigger to PropertyChanged (it's default is LostFocus). This will solve so many issues...

Answer (score 1):

If you search for `FocusManager` then you will find two kind of `FocusManager` class. But you have to go for

[`Windows.UI.Xaml.Input.FocusManager`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.xaml.input.focusmanager%28v=win.10%29.aspx)

not

[`System.Windows.Input.FocusManager`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms604088.aspx).

It has static method `GetFocusedElement()` which queries the focus system to determine which object in the UI has focus.

Answer (score 0):

There is a [`FocusManager`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms604088.aspx)-class, which might help you. Use the textbox' parent as scope-element.